# Emacs 24.3 python mode indents code after end of a function incorrectly

Tags: python, emacs, indentation

I am writing some Python code in Emacs, but when I have finished a function block and I want to define the next function, the line is automatically indented:

```
def funA(x):
    print("Hello!")
    return 1

def funB(y):<--- cursor is here, when I press RET line is automatically indented!
```

As `def` is supposed to be in the first column, how can I make Emacs not do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug which has been fixed in the current development version of Emacs:

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18228

As a temporary fix, you can use this code, which causes `electric-indent-mode` not to re-indent the current line on a colon:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq electric-indent-chars '(?\n))))
```